# loading scope value into an array doesnt work in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arraylist, angularjs-scope, view-scope

```
Please consider the small angularJs code snippet below.

$scope.myArray = [];
function sampleMethod(){
    $scope.myArray.push({
        name: $scope.name,
        age: $scope.age
    });
    console.log($scope.myArray.name);
};
```

Here, I was trying to get the scope values name and age and loading it to a scope array inside a controller. But the above program prints nothing. Cant we access and feed scope values to an array from controller? If not possible, how can I do it correctly?

Comment: You have declared the function `sampleMethod` but you have not made a function call.. So there will be nothing on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Cuco Pérez';
    $scope.age = 37;
    $scope.myArray = [];

    (function sampleMethod() {
        $scope.myArray.push({
            name: $scope.name,
            age: $scope.age
        });
        console.log($scope.myArray[0].name);
    })();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Hi, my name is: {{ myArray[0].name }}</h1>    
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your $scope.myArray is an array, not an object.

DO this,  **$scope.myArray[0].name** it should work.